# Python copy column data of workbook of named X to another workbook named Y

Tags: python

I am in trouble with simple copy of column data of 1 workbook to another workbook's column.

I have work book named data.xls which has a column A filled with 40 000 rows. (A1:A40000). I want its data to be copied to another work book named main.xls. on same location called A1:A40000. I am trying following code.

```
import xlwt    
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xls')    
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
i= 0
a= 40000
for i in range(0,int(a)): 
    data = [sheet.cell_value(i,0) for col in range(sheet.ncols)]
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')
for index, value in enumerate(data):
sheet.write(i, index, value)
workbook.save('main.xls')
```

but this code is printing at only 40 000 location rest all are blanks. so i got only 1 data of location A40000.

Answer (score 0):

try this. you only need one for loop.

```
import xlwt    
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xlsx')    
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
workbook2 = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet2 = workbook2.add_sheet('test')
i= 0
a= 40000
for i in range(0,int(a)): 

    data = [sheet.cell_value(i, 0)]
    sheet2.write(i,0, str(data[0]))

workbook2.save('main.xls')
```

Comment: it shows error that name index is not defined. @joshi123

Comment: apologies - edited. index is simply `0`, data is the value being written. Column A in excel would be `0`, column B is `1`, etc

Comment: not working showing error: unexpected data type %r % type (data)

Comment: ah yes, that solution only worked for strings ( i couldn't see your data). answer edited, try it now.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.  but everytime this making file main.xls  how can i write data directly to another excel file's column. it should not genearte or make file everytime. another thing is can i make xlsx file using this xlrd and xlwt modules? @ joshi123

Comment: glad it works. If you have further questions in addition to the original problem, you should pose them in a new question.